# toggleClass is not working on foundation

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, toggleclass

I have this class on a css page on a page that is using foundation from Zurb.

```
.brandingOpen{
height:2044px;

}
```

and I have a button which id is
`#zoomBranding`, so far I have tried this with no result at all.

```
$("zoomBranding").click(function(){

$("#branding").toggleClass("brandingOpen");


}
);
```

not working at all, if I put an alert, this works good, but the toggleClass not.

So far I've tried this with results but only one time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#zoomBranding").click(function(){

    $(this).toggleClass( function(){
    $("#branding").css("height", "2044px");
    $(this).addClass("fi-zoom-out");
    $(this).click( function(){
        $("#branding").css("height", "1044px");

    });

    }
    );


}
);
}
);
```

I cannot use classes in the #branding, even using the .addClass so if anyone knows what am I doing wrong, please help me.

Using the version of query that is already packed with Foundation 4 and even trying with the jquery-migrate at the top of everything, is the same result.

here is the css for #branding.

```
#branding{
height:1044px;
overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
  transition: height 0.5s linear;


}

.brandingOpen{
    height:2044px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem related to the [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) where by rules specified by the ID selector has precedence over rules from class selectors.

```
#branding {
    height:1044px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    transition: height 0.5s linear;
}
#branding.brandingOpen {
    height:2044px;
}
```

Also it looks like there is a minor script issue, so try

```
$("zoomBranding").click(function () {
    $("branding").toggleClass("brandingOpen");
});
```

Comment: ok so if I do the brabnding .brandingOpen it will work with the toggle class, just it...I'll try it right now.  thanks.

Comment: ok, I did it but is not working this was my jquery and it didn't work.

Comment: $("#zoomBranding").click(function(){
 
 $("#branding").toogleClass("brandingOpen");
 
 
 
}
);

Comment: @GustavoDuenas can you share the html

Comment: <div id="branding" class="row ">
    <h1 class="invisible">Branding and Marketing in Jacksonville, FL</h1>
    <img src="images/branding.jpg"/>
    
      <div  style="height:5px; background-color:#999" class="shadowNew"></div>
    <img src="images/branding2.jpg"/>
    <i id="zoomBranding" style="font-size:24px;"class="fi-zoom-in"></i>
    <div class="branding">
    <h1 class="small-12 columns" align="right"> Branding</h1>
    <p class="small-6 columns">
    
   </p>
    <span>
    
    </span>
    
    </div>   ///let me know what might be.

Comment: well in my page doesn't might be and issue related with foundation from zurb? here is my page for you to see. I even have put a jquery in the top, but it doesn't make any difference at all. http://leftandrightsolutions.com

Comment: @GustavoDuenas see the updated script... it seems to be working on your site

Answer (score 0):

finally after some research I got it, from some strange reason foundation won't use toggleClass on an id #branding, instead I do create a class and then I interchange the class I put e for event in the function from the click and right now is working, this was the code

```
$("#zoomBranding").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".closedNow").toggleClass("brandingOpen");
    $(this).toggleClass("fi-zoom-out");


}
);
```